# Unordered index when concatenating dataframes with categorical features

Tags: python, pandas

The code bellow is made up to make the understanding of my question easier. I want to create an overview table, and in order to do so, I will loop through to all unique elements of the column 'Order', creating a dataframe for each unique element of that column and afterwards I will get the percentage represented by each element of the column 'Status' with .value_counts, proceeding to save it into another dataframe, which is my overview table.

```
Overview_Table = pd.DataFrame()
for i, val in enumerate(df['Order'):
    dfi = df.loc[df['Order']==val]
    status = pd.DataFrame(dfi['Status Situation'].value_counts(normalize = True))
    statusi.columns = ['Order: {}'.format(val)]
    Overview_Table = pd.concat([Overview_Table, statusi], axis=1)
```

The problem that I am facing is that when I keep concatenating values to the Overview_Table, these values are not being concatenated in the same order. Hence, what I am looking for is to figure out a way to keep appending the status dataframe to the Overview_Table dataframe always on the same order.

I already tried to use `.sort_index` however I haven't had any success. Also, the column 'Order' and 'Status' are both categorical features.

Hope that I managed to be succinct and precise. I would really appreciate your help on this one! Suggestions of what to look up for are also welcome

Comment: can you show us what you need ? Also , if the index same , the concat will show the same order .

Comment: @WeNYoBen unfortunately this is not what is happening. The concatenation is not preserving the order. I would  expect the concat to return exactly the same index order, but somehow this is not what the script is returning. So, l will have all the unique elements of the column 'Status Situation' as index, however the elements that are returned by ```.value_counts``` are not being concatenated according to their index. Not sure if I managed to clarify everything, but if not, feel free to ask for additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think* this is what you're looking for..

Create a random dataset with order and status, and some random numbers:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
order = [random.choice(['aa', 'bb', 'cc']) for _ in range(1000)]
status = [random.choice(['red', 'yellow', 'green']) for _ in range(1000)]
nums = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(1000)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'order':order,
                   'status':status,
                   'value':nums})
```

group by the order and status and sum the values:

```
g = df.groupby(['order', 'status']).agg({'value':'sum'}).reset_index(drop=False)
```

group by just the order and sum the values (to get the denominator)

```
order_g = df.groupby('order')['value'].sum().reset_index(drop=False)
```

combine them by doing a left join:

```
combined = pd.merge(g, order_g, on='order', how='left')
```

create the percentage (value_counts normalize):

```
combined['percentage'] = combined['value_x']/combined['value_y']
```

drop the unneeded columns:

```
combined.drop(['value_x', 'value_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Without an actual dataset that you provide, and the expectation of what you're looking for, its hard to answer this for certain but I believe this is what you're looking for.